# VS2010 code analysis. Suppress message CA1051:DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields for all class members

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop, suppressmessage

I have a class like this one:

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly int A = 1;
    public readonly int B = 2;
}
```

When I run VS2010 built in Code Analysis tool, I get **2** identical warnings:
that '*field '...' is visible outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility to private and add a property, with the same accessibility as the field has currently, to provide access to it*'.

I want to suppress this warning for all fields in my class **Foo**, but I don't want to mark every field with SuppressMessage attribute like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1051:DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields")]
    public readonly int A = 1;
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1051:DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields")]
    public readonly int B = 2;
}
```

I want to mark all class members, using code like this:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1051:DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields")]
public class Foo
{
    public readonly int A = 1;
    public readonly int B = 2;
}
```

But this code doesn't work, I still get a code analysis warning.
How can I do it correctly?

Comment: I think you found a bug, post to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: any final solution about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to suppress more than 1 message at a time using SuppressMessageAttribute.

As discussion can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/a4b5d7b4-a221-4f3e-bd38-e016b39f72c9), but the relevant part is:

> You are running into a common misunderstanding about SuppressMessage.
>
> Each time you put a SuppressMessage in a source file, you suppress
>   exactly one problem (one "row" in the grid).  Period.
>
> A SuppressMessage may be placed either "near" the violation or at the
>   module-level.  Module-level, assembly-level, and global suppression
>   all mean the same thing.  By placing at the module-level, you do not
>   suppress multiple instances of the problem at once.  You merely get to
>   locate the SuppressMessage in a different place of the code.  The main
>   benefit is that you can, for example, collect all the suppressions
>   related to the assembly in a single file (for example,
>   GlobalSuppressions.cs).
>
> When you use a module-level SuppressMessage, you must specify the
>   Target.  The Target must match exactly what is reported in the GUI for
>   a violation of the rule.
>
> There is no way to use SuppressMessage to suppress a rule for the
>   entire scope of a class or the entire scope of a namespace.

Comment: Thanks you very much! It seems I really didn't understand SuppressMessage concept correctly! Your ansver helped me much. Now I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the CodeAnalysis rules file with a set of rules like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="10.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis"
         RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
    <Rule Id="CA1111" Action="Ignore" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

See step by step walkthrough:

- [Code Analysis without Visual Studio 2010](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2011/01/code-analysis-without-visual-studio_6701.html)
- [Download an example](http://www.users.on.net/~kentcb/code_analysis/CodeAnalysisIntegrationExample.zip)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to suppress this rule for the all code in my application. Is there a way to suppress this rule for the one class only?

Comment: @feorex: IIRC you can define SupressMessage attribute for any particular method