# Field name does not start with underscore - sonar issue

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We are following Hungarian notation to declare private variables as below.

```
private IRepository<Request> _requestRepo;

public RequestService(IRepository<Request> requestRepo)
{
    _requestRepo = requestRepo;
}
```

The above code shows a sonar issue like Field name does not start with underscore. Please tell me how to declare the private variables to satisfy coding standards?

Comment: By not making it start with an underscore, or by disabling the warning temporarily ([`SuppressMessage`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092778/vs2010-code-analysis-suppress-message-ca1051donotdeclarevisibleinstancefields)) or by disabling the rule altogether. See [To underscore or to not to underscore, that is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450238/to-underscore-or-to-not-to-underscore-that-is-the-question).

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use hungarian notation for C#, it's very, very obsolete. Use the [Microsoft Coding Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The whole .NET world is designed with those in mind, going against it will make your code stick out like a sore thumb.

That said, the guidelines aren't clear about rules for private fields. It's common to either use an underscore or `camelCase`. If you use Microsoft Visual Studio, use the Code Analysis feature (formerly known as FxCop) to get hints like make your private variable `readonly` in this case.

Your error message does not make any sense. If the message says your field name *should not* start with an underscore, I'd suggest `camelCase` as per the Microsoft Guidelines.